# How to Focus on JS appended HTML after click?

Tags: javascript

When clicking a button a script loads new HTML into the markup. I want the focus on this new HTML once it loads ( its a modal).

I managed to focus on this modal only when inserting a timeout after the initial click was triggered. When inserting the code without the timeout JS doesn't find the HTML element I am looking for. Is there another way of solving this?

THIS DOES NOT WORK:

```
document.querySelector("#asp-popup-red-button").addEventListener("click", 
 function(){
  const newHTML = document.querySelector('#popup-modal')
  console.log(newHTML);
})
```

RESULT: NULL

THIS WORKS:

```
document.querySelector("#asp-popup-red-button").addEventListener("click", 
 function(){
  setTimeout(function(){ 
  const newHTML = document.querySelector('#popup-modal')
  console.log(newHTML);

  }, 500);

})
```

RESULT: Div Element ....

Comment: Please post a [MCVE]. It sounds like you need to wait for an asynchronous call to complete

Comment: can you post working jsfiddle

Comment: I will see what I can do. Its basically a code overwriting the standard POPUP of ELEMENTOR ( theme builder for WP), so there is no way I can actually JSfiddle that :S

Comment: The operation inserting the new HTML is probably happening async, so it would make sense that a delayed response has more chance to be correctly triggered. If theres a slow connection, though, that doesnt work. Is there no way to know when new HTML has been loaded, like with a Promise or something? Otherwise you will have to just created an interval and see when the new HTML is attached and exists so you can focus it.

Comment: thank you for your replies. I will just keep it the way I have it using a timeout.